# Phalcon 3.2 Volt двойной рендеринг основного шаблона

Tags: php, шаблоны, phalcon

В основном шаблоне имеется следующий код:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
        <title>Phalcon PHP Framework</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        {{ partial( 'partials/menu' ) }}
        {{ partial( 'partials/messages' ) }}

        <div class="container">
            {{ content() }}
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

В `partials/menu` лежит Bootstrap'нутое меню, в `partials/messages` лежит вывод flashMessages. Нас интересует `content()`. В контроллере следующий код (лишнее убрано):

```
public function showAction()
{
    // $id приходит из запроса
    $post = Post::findById( $id );
    // в шаблоне переменная single_post будет называться
    $this->view->setVar( 'single_post', $post );
    // рендерится шаблон app/views/post/one.volt
    return $this->view->render( 'post', 'one' );
}
```

При этом основной шаблон почему-то рендерится два раза. То есть, основной шаблон - в нём на месте строчки `{{ content() }}` ещё раз вставляется он-же, вместе с `<html>` и `<head>` и меню, полностью. А вот уже во вложенном шаблоне на месте контента появляется пост с вёрсткой из `one.volt`. При этом (внимание) другой шаблон (`all.volt`), в котором массив постов через `{% for post in posts %}` перебирается и для каждого подгружается `one.volt`, отрабатывает нормально. То есть основной шаблон, в нём на месте строчки `{{ content() }}` разметка ленты, и в ленте корректно посты. Почему так? Как исправить?

PHP 7, Nginx, Phalcon 3.2, Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Из ситуации вышел следующим образом. Вместо

```
return $this->view->render( 'post', 'one' );
```

написал

```
return $this->view->pick( 'post/one' );
```

...ну и по аналогии в других местах заменил. Теперь всё работает как нужно.